# "buf" argument must be a string or an instance of Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, buffer, cloudinary

I use nestjs and want to upload image on cloudinary and use this [instruction](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjE-rb98Lr_AhUIpIsKHQlAB0wQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fcodex%2Fhow-to-upload-images-to-cloudinary-using-nestjs-9f496460e8d7&usg=AOvVaw3Ok0wZ-Wh_yfi6XKjl2nnu) for do it.

But i getting the error

```
ERROR [RpcExceptionsHandler] "buf" argument must be a string or an instance of Buffer
```

TypeError: "buf" argument must be a string or an instance of Buffer

My file.buffer have type buffer

[image]

How can I upload image?

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UploadApiErrorResponse, UploadApiResponse, v2 } from 'cloudinary';
import toStream = require('buffer-to-stream');
@Injectable()
export class CloudinaryService {
  async uploadImage(file: Express.Multer.File): Promise<UploadApiResponse | UploadApiErrorResponse> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const upload = v2.uploader.upload_stream((error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        resolve(result);
      });
      toStream(file.buffer).pipe(upload);
    });
  }
}
```

module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CloudinaryServiceController } from './cloudinary-service.controller';
import { CloudinaryService } from './cloudinary-service.service';
import { CloudinaryProvider } from './cloudinary-service.provider';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [CloudinaryServiceController],
  providers: [CloudinaryProvider, CloudinaryService],
  exports: [CloudinaryProvider, CloudinaryService],
})
export class CloudinaryServiceModule {}
```

Comment: Can you share more of the code around this?

Comment: Ok, i added service and module code

Comment: You've told Typescript the `file` is an `Express.Multer.File`, but what about where you're calling the service from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have actually used `v2.uploader.upload(file.buffer, (error, result)` instead of `v2.uploader.upload_stream((error, result)` and everything would have worked alright. But since you want to convert it to a stream, you need to ensure that the `toStream` function is properly converting the buffer to a readable stream. Use `Readable.from` method from node stream for this.

Updated service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UploadApiErrorResponse, UploadApiResponse, v2 } from 'cloudinary';
import { Readable } from 'stream';

@Injectable()
export class CloudinaryService {
  async uploadImage(file: Express.Multer.File): Promise<UploadApiResponse | UploadApiErrorResponse> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const upload = v2.uploader.upload_stream((error, result) => {
        if (error) return reject(error);
        resolve(result);
      });

      const readableStream = Readable.from(file.buffer);
      readableStream.pipe(upload);
    });
  }
}
```